# Is it a good idea to use reflections in a Web application?

Tags: java, oop

I have developed below code with the intention to remove if else conditions so that code cyclomatic complexity should be less.
For this I have used reflection api and wrote method which takes condition as an argument and called respective method on the condition name basis.
This works fine, I want to know is it a good idea to use reflection (This code) in web application, so that I am free from checking conditions.

For example in below code we have different method with prefix state ex: stateSUBMIT, stateWithdraw etc.
we can call stateSUBMIT method by passing only "SUBMIT".

```
public class Participate {

    public String execute(String methodName) {

        String st = null;
        try {

            Method method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                    "state" + methodName);
            method.invoke(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return st;
    }

    public void stateSUBMIT() {
        System.out.println("in SUBMIT");
    }

    public void stateWithdraw() {
        System.out.println("in Withdraw");
    }

    public void state() {
        System.out.println("in state ");
    }

    public void statenull() {
        System.out.println("in null ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Participate p = new Participate();
        p.execute("SUBMIT");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid code, but can be achieved without reflections.

**Step One: Define an interface**

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute();
}
```

**Step Two: Create Concrete Implementations**

```
public class StateCommand implements Command {
    public void execute() {
        // Your code.
    }
}
```

**Step Three: Add a collection of these to your original class**

```
private Map<String, Command> commands;
```

**Step Four: Populate**

```
public MyClass() {
    commands = new HashMap<String, Command>();
    commands.put("state", new StateCommand());
}
```

**Get that class and execute**

```
public String callMethod(String name) {
    Command command = commands.get(name);
    if(command != null) {
        command.execute();
    }
}
```

This is just a relatively simple alternative to using reflections, which should be considered as a last resort.

Comment: I agree, even though, if the implementations are short, you might consider making the concrete `Command` implementations anonymous. Moreover, this has the benefit of better performance (theoretically anyway). Having said that, I would not go as far as saying that the proposed solution should be a last resort, it sure is better than a long unreadable and untestable `if` condition.

Comment: Certainly! Reflections gets a very bad rap, but it has a lot of good uses in a lot of different places. It's just that in this context, I think this solution is a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid it. There are better alternatives. You could pick one of all the numerous web frameworks or you could code something similar without reflection. For example, use a HashMap from the action (SUBMIT, ...) to an object that implements an interface. That way you can call a method with parameters without reflection, which is slow and which provides no compile-time validations. This is not a recommendation (go with a framework!), but it is a better way of doing what you are doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is beneficial in case if you are doing for making this Generic approach for all other other classes in your project.Its good if you are having re usability of this in many other scenarios. 
But if its only for specific implementation which is not generalized then there are many simple ways to do this job, because if you will use java reflections than there is some amount of time complexity involved which is comparatively less if you do it without using reflectns.